# Is this the formula for the conditional covariance of normally distributed random variables?

Tags: distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, covariance, multivariate-normal-distribution

Assuming $X$, $Y$, and $Z$ are normally distributed random variables, is it true that:

$Cov[X, Y | Z] = Cov[X, Y] - Cov[X, Z]Cov[Y, Z] / Var[Z]$

Could you provide a simple derivation?

Comment: What does your formula imply when $Z$ is a constant?  For general formulas, please [search our site](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=normal+conditional+distribution).

Comment: Mmm I am not following...why would Z be a constant?

Comment: Because it's a simple case of a multivariate Normal distribution.  Thus, if your formula makes sense in general it must make sense for such special cases.

Comment: So does it mean the formula is wrong? Would you kindly provide a direct answer to the question? What am I missing?

Comment: Over the course of this year, many of us have directed you to the answers that exist on this site.  I urge you to search them out and apply them.

Comment: I know that $Var[X|Z]=Var[X]−(Cov[X,Z])^2/Var[Z]$ (the standard conditional variance for gaussians, which exists on this site), but about the conditional covariance which I provided?

Comment: What if I ask you in which scenarios my formula applies and in which it doesn't? Would it be an independent question which you would address?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149531/discussion-between-anonymous-and-whuber).

Comment: @whuber the following answers my question: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/386936/conditional-covariance-of-a-multivariate-normal-vector

Comment: Thank you for identifying it: linking to duplicate questions adds to the value of this site because it provides multiple ways for future readers to find what they need.